# Cause of seasons

Tags: orbital-motion, sun

NB: I live in the northern hemisphere so when I say summer and winter I'm referring to ~July and ~January respectively.

I've been reading online about the cause of the Earth's seasons and I'm still rather confused. The explanations I have read state that the Earth's tilt is the cause of the seasons, because the part of the Earth tilted towards the sun must receive more solar energy. This makes sense to me because that part of the earth is closer to the sun. But it is also made clear that the distance between the Earth and the sun has no (or negligible) effect, and that counterintuitively we are closest to the Sun in the winter and furthest away in the summer. This doesn't make much sense to me though. The diameter of the Earth is only 12,742 km. Due to Earth's elliptical orbit, it is 147,093,602 km away from the sun in the winter and 152,097,053 km away in the summer. The difference between the two is 5,003,451 km. This is significantly larger than amount by which we move to and away from the sun as a result of the Earth's tilt, which will be at most 12,742km, and given that the angle of tilt is only about 23.5 degrees, it will be a lot less than this. It seems to me that the effect of the Earth's tilt should be cancelled out by the much larger difference in orbital distance. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of radiation absorbed by a surface is proportional to the intensity of the beam of light (from the Sun in this case) multiplied by the cosine of the angle between the beam direction and a normal to the surface.

In other words, when a surface is tilted at an angle to the light source it absorbs less energy.

This is what is happening with the Earth. In summer, the Sun is higher in the sky (on average) and it's radiation falls more directly onto the Earth's surface. In winter the Sun is lower in the sky and the angle between the sunlight and a normal to the surface is larger.

The distance between the surface of the Earth and the Sun plays almost no role in the seasons.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.